# Array outputting random numbers from memory during random generation of numbers into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#ifndef REQUESTGENERATOR_H_
#define REQUESTGENERATOR_H_

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class requestGenerator {
public:
int randomStar = 0;
int amountOfEvents = 0;
int randomEventArray[10];
int possibleEventArray[15] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};

void generator() {

    while (randomStar <= 2) {
        randomStar = rand() % 5;    
    }
    cout <<  randomStar << endl;

    while (amountOfEvents == 0) {
        amountOfEvents = rand() % 10;
    }
    cout << amountOfEvents << endl;



    for (int i = 0; i != amountOfEvents; i++) {
        bool numberGened = false;
        while (numberGened = false) {
            randomEventArray[i] = rand() % 15;

            if (possibleEventArray[i] != -1) {
                numberGened = true;
                possibleEventArray[i] = -1;
            }
        }
        cout << randomEventArray[i] << " ";

    }

  }
};


#endif  /*REQUESTGENERATOR_H_ */
```

When it outputs the generated number it gives -858993460 nine times. I am not sure why. 'possibleEventArray' is meant to hold all possible values. While the generated number goes into randomEventArray

Comment: i have the feeling that you wand to check `possibleEventArray[ rand()%15 ]` instead of `possibleEventArray[ i]`. Further, it seems like you want to generate a random permutation of the elements in `possibleEventArray`. For this there are duplicates around

Comment: i mean `if (possibleEventArray[i] != -1)` will be `true` always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never actually filling the array because of this `while (numberGened = false)`.  You're missing a second equals sign.  As written, all you're doing is setting `numberGened` to `false` and not even entering the loop because `numberGened = false` returns the value, which is `false`.

Some other unsolicited comments on this:

```
while (randomStar <= 2) {
    randomStar = rand() % 5;    
}
```

If this is meant to generate a random number between 3 and 5, you can do that with `randomStart = 3 + rand() % 3`, as opposed to a while loop.

This `for (int i = 0; i != amountOfEvents; i++)` should really be `i < amountOfEvents`, otherwise you risk a really long loop if you modify i somewhere that goes beyond `amountOfEvents`.

Comment: Its now showing real numbers, but now it is also showing the same numbers everytime. I'm using visual studio, ive cleaned the solution.

Comment: I suggest stepping through this with a debugger (or if you don't want to do that, just litter it with `cout` to see step by step)